# JavaScript Canvas closePath() and straight lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've used round capped lines on moveTo() -> [lineTo()] -> closePath() on a subroutine that draws "spots", lines and more complex lines. If there is only one lineTo() on the drawing the capped line behaves oddly:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>HTML5 Canvas</h1>
<h2>The lineCap Property</h2>

<p>Zero length rounded end line with "ctx.closePath" dissappears in Firefox:</p>
<p>Non-zero length rounded end line with "ctx.closePath" looses caps in Firefox & Chrome:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="50" height="80" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>

<script>
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(20, 40);
ctx.lineTo(20, 40);
ctx.closePath(); // <-- THIS WILL HIDE THE LINE ON FIREFOX!
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(20, 60);
ctx.lineTo(21, 60);
ctx.closePath(); // <-- THIS WILL LOOSE CAPS ON FIREFOX AND CHROME!
ctx.stroke();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The script draws diffrently on latest Firefox (116.0) and Chrome (115.0...). Is it not permitted to use closePath() if there is only one lineTo() on drawing routine?

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately still a compat' issue, indeed, and there is no easy way around.

[The specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#trace-a-path) ask to "prune" all zero length paths before rendering, but then when it's time to render the line-cap, they ask that such zero-length path is rendered as if there was actually two points:

> 2. Prune all zero-length line segments from path.
> 3. Remove from path any subpaths containing no lines (i.e. subpaths with just one point).

[...]

> 9. [...]
>    Points with no lines coming out of them must have two caps placed back-to-back as if it was really two points connected to each other by an infinitesimally short straight line in the direction of the point's directionality (as defined above).
>    which Safari does, but Firefox renders them, and Chrome used to draw only if there was both a `moveTo` and a `lineTo` to the same point, but they recently changed that behavior to match the specs and Safari (this is currently only available in the *Canary* version of Chrome).

This is a [very old issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1079), that has still not been resolved: there are compelling arguments in both sides. Safari does follow the steps *2.* and *3.*, meaning that they do remove such zero-length subpaths, Firefox renders them, matching the rest of the algorithm, and Chrome used to draw them only if there was both a `moveTo` and a `lineTo` to the same point, but they recently changed that behavior to match the specs and Safari (this is currently only available in the *Canary* version of Chrome).

So this is a first issue, that you apparently didn't see yet, and which only concerns the top path.

---

Now, when you call `closePath()`, the subpath is enclosed, which means that there is no end points to it anymore, they've been converted to joins, so there shouldn't be any line-cap being drawn, since these are drawn only on end points.

> 5. Add a straight closing line to each closed subpath in path connecting the last point and the first point of that subpath; change the last point to a join (from the previously last line to the newly added closing line), and change the first point to a join (from the newly added closing line to the first line).

Safari's behavior (which matches the current specs) is relatively obvious as it will prune the subpath even before checking if it has to render line-caps or not. Firefox's behavior is quite consistent, since there is no end-points anymore, they don't draw the line-cap when the subpath is closed. Chrome's old behavior (current stable) is arguably the most wrong one, as they did render the line-cap even though there is no end-points, but their new behavior matches Safari's one and they don't render anything at all.

And finally your third example shows one more discrepancy here, since Safari will render a weird 2px dot in the middle of the 1px x 15px stroke. This honestly looks like a bug, but given the compat issue here, I'm not sure it's worth opening a bug report just yet.

---

#### And what can I do about it?

As I said at the beginning there is no easy way around. First, you'll indeed want to not call `closePath()` if you want line-caps to be rendered. Then, regarding the first issue, the best might be to avoid the situation entirely and search yourself if in your data there will be such a zero length subpath, and `fill()` an `arc()` manually.
But switching between `stroke()` and `fill()` in the middle of drawing a path may not be convenient. So another workaround is to move one of the coords by a very small amount (`1e-6` should be both small and safe enough, higher precision may not work as coords are converted to `float` internally) so that the engine doesn't see it as a single-point sub-path.